# FUSE overlay mount with colon in path

Tags: fuse, union-mount

Is it possible to do an overlay mount when one of the paths has a colon in it? All of the FUSE overlay mounting solutions I've looked at use a colon to separate the paths in the overlay, and I can't find a way to escape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Directory Structure

Let's say we're trying to overlay `foo:bar`, and `bar:baz`. The mount point will be `union`

```
foo
└── a
bar
└── b
foo:bar
└── c
bar:baz
└── d
union
```

## `mergerfs`

No matter what escaping you try to do, you can [see from the source](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs/blob/2.24.2/src/option_parser.cpp#L240) that it won't work. Annoyingly if you try to guess a way to escape it:

```
$ mergerfs 'foo\:bar':'bar\:baz' union
```

it won't throw an error, but will silently ignore directories that don't exist:

```
$ ls union
b
```

## `unionfs-fuse`

[Same problem](https://github.com/rpodgorny/unionfs-fuse/blob/v2.0/src/opts.c#L218) as `mergerfs`, no way to escape a colon. At least it'll fail with an error though if a directory doesn't exist:

```
$ unionfs-fuse 'foo\:bar':'bar\:baz' union
Failed to open /foo\/: No such file or directory. Aborting!
```

## `overlayfs`

`overlayfs` *does* allow escaping colons in paths, but it's not a FUSE filesystem.

```
$ mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir='foo\:bar':'bar\:baz' union
$ ls union
c  d
```

## Workaround

A simple workaround that works with both `mergerfs` and `unionfs-fuse` is to use a symlink:

```
$ ln -s foo:bar foo_bar
$ ln -s bar:baz bar_baz
$ unionfs-fuse foo_bar:bar_baz union
$ ls union
c  d
```